# Connection Error (Couldnt get any Response) unable to post on Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have tried to post in MongoDB by using postman while posting a text i got a error of (Couldnt get any Response) It is not showing any error to Command nodemon Please help me where i did mistake ..!  what i need to do ?

My **index.js** file is:-

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const config = require('./configdb/database');

// Connection to database
mongoose.connect(config.database);

// Connection Success to DB
mongoose.connection.on('connected',() => {
    console.log('Connected to the Database ' +config.database);
});

//on Error while Connecting
mongoose.connection.on('error',(err) => {
    console.log('connection ERROR Try Again Database Failed to Connect ' +err);
});

const app = express();
const articles = require('./routers/articles');

// Port to start 
const port = 2200;

// cors middleware
app.use(cors());

// Set Static Public folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/articles',articles);

// Index Route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('this is initial page for starting all session')
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('server started in' + port)
})
```

my **articles.js** file is

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const config = require('../configdb/database');
const Article = require('../models/article');

// Register of article
router.post('/new-article', (req,res,next) => {

    let article = new Article();
    article.title = req.body.title;

    console.log(req.body.title);
    return;

    article.save(function(err){
        if(err){
              res.json({success: false, msg: 'Failed to Register the Article' });

        } else {
            res.json({success: true, msg: 'New Article is Registered'});
        }
    });

});

module.exports = router;
```

my **article.js** file is

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('../configdb/database');

const ArticleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title:{
        type: String,
    }
});

const Article = module.exports = mongoose.model('Article', ArticleSchema)
```

**But I have got the message from 
    `article.title = req.body.title;`** and my error as follows:-

[image: Postman and Nodemon ScreenShot]

Comment: what is return statement after console.log ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In articles.js you have return the function after displaying title cause the problem!

```
// Register of article
router.post('/new-article', (req, res, next) => {

    let article = new Article();
    article.title = req.body.title;

    console.log(req.body.title);
    // return;

    article.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({
                success: false,
                msg: 'Failed to Register the Article'
            });

        } else {
            res.json({
                success: true,
                msg: 'New Article is Registered'
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you @Programmer21 I got the solution But Can i know why Return Function cause me Problem..?

Comment: In JavaScript, return statements cease execution in a function and return a value to the caller; JavaScript functions require an explicit return statement for returning the result of an expression (the value) from a function. When a return statement is not present, the interpreter automatically returns undefined.

Comment: stop the execution and return the value where you have written 'return'.